# Как получить текст из textEdit PySide6

Tags: python, gui, pyside, qtextedit, pyside6

обычный `.text()` не работает

```py
ui.textEdit_3.text()
```

Нужно получить текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PySide6.QtWidgets.QTextEdit.**toPlainText**()
>
> Возвращает текст редактирования текста как обычный текст.